# How to create .docx file in iPhone app programmatically?

Tags: iphone

Here is my code:-

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *temp =  @"Data to be written in file";
NSData *adata =[temp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
documentsDir = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Document.docx"];
[adata writeToFile:documentsDir atomically:YES];
```

When i open this file in the document folder the problem that i face is that "File is invalid". Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to create a file in `docx` format, or one just with that extension? Where do you get the file is invalid error from?

Comment: i created text file using this code so i thought i can creat a doc file as well so i tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`docx` files are zip-compressed XML documents with a layout defined by Microsoft. You can't just write text out to a file, call it a docx and expect word to open it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205%28v=office.12%29.aspx good luck ;)

Comment: thanks for the useful info i was not knowing the structure of docx file.